# KernelBase.dll crashing from multiple games

Tags: windows-10, crash, kernel

Kernelbase.dll is being logged as the faulting module in EventViewer from multiple games (And crashing the games) when they attempt to load a multiplayer lobby. From multiple games they all log KernelBase.dll as the faulting module with the same exception code and fault offset.

A couple of example games are the new "Savage Resurrection" and "Space Engineers".

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.494, time stamp: 0x5775e4c5
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
```

I am running Windows 10 enterprise. I've tried a few things, sfc /scannow, checking the output log of sfc it didnt even detect KernelBase.dll as having a fault. Ran a chkdsk on all of my drives to ensure nothing is crazy there, all fine.
Any help in diagnosing this issue would be grand. I cant find much online about the exception code.

Edit: Upgraded to 1607 and same error, different offset:

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899809
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000017788
```

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to Version 1607, based on the version displayed, your not running the current version of Windows 10.

Comment: Strange, Windows updates say no updates to install. I'd be confident I was on the latest version if you didn't say that. any ideas?

Comment: 10.0.10586 is Version 1511, how you update Enterprise versions of Windows 10 to Version 1607, is documented on this website by other questions with answers.

Comment: Since you still have Version 1511, it means you can try uninstalling, KB3132372

Comment: I would rather upgrade than downgrade to fix issues. Looking for the question you suggested now. :)

Comment: http://www.infoworld.com/article/3018915/microsoft-windows/win10-flash-patch-kb-3132372-breaks-skype-hp-solutions-center-incredimail-games.html  that KB has known to cause problems.  There is no promise that going to Version 1607 won't bring the issue with you though.

Comment: After upgrading, same error. :(

Comment: Any other ideas @Ramhound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head scratching and many days of trying different things. I did a reset of my PC (keeping personal files, etc)

The issue is no longer present (and i'm still on 1607)